# Cannot Scaffold-DbContext with EntityFrameworkCore.Jet on EF Core 5

Tags: entity-framework-core, jet-ef-provider

I want to scaffold an old ms access database (.mdb). So I create a sln with Visual Studio 2019 for a console app. Then with nuget I add the following packages:

```
EntityFrameworkCore.Jet" Version="3.1.0-alpha.4" 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.5" 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.5"
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.5"
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.5"
```

In the package manager console I enter

Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Repo\Samp.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=****
;" -Provider EntityFrameworkCore.Jet -OutputDir Models\Models600 -verbose

The command runs and I get the following error:

Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.DecimalTypeMapping..ctor(System.String, System.Nullable`1<System.Data.DbType>)'.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: You need to downgrade your EF Core dependencies to 3.1

Comment: I read their dependencies wrong saw 5.0.0 and moved on

Comment: EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Data (>= 3.1.0-alpha.4)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 3.1.10 && < 5.0.0)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 3.1.10 && < 5.0.0)